# Getting names of participants MSConversation

Tags: objective-c, imessage

I am developing an iMessage app where I need to get the names of participants of a conversation. 
In the WWDC Session *iMessage Apps and Stickers, Part 2* ([link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/224/)), they are explaining how to do that in Swift via String interpolation :

```
layout.caption = "$\(conversation.localParticipantIdentifier.uuidString) likes Sprinkles!"
```

The thing is I want to do the same in Objective-C and I can't find any documentation on how to perform string interpolation in Objective-C or how to achieve showing the name of the participants.

I have tried

```
[layout setCaption:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$\(%@)",conversation.localParticipantIdentifier.UUIDString]];
```

but it is showing the entire UUID instead of the participant name.
There must be a Objective-C way!

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the solution.

I just needed to add a dollar sign before the UUID.

```
[layout setCaption:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",self.activeConversation.localParticipantIdentifier.UUIDString]];
```

Comment: This is theory because in practice this gives wrong results and don't identify the local participant... not on simulator and on the real device this produces a "mobile user" result... come on Apple!